# Amazon web services mysql2 database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-web-services

So I had a working web database that was hosted by xeround. After the subscription ended I tried to make my own database as seen in [The website](http://blog.aizatto.com/2007/05/15/setting-up-ruby-on-rails-database-connection-using-mysql-on-ubuntu-feisty-fawn/)

Anyways I followed those steps up to Locking MySQL.

And when I try to run it on my domain name say *dog.com*

It gives me the error

> Access denied for user 'hostname'@'ip-xxxx' (using password: YES)

What can I do to fix this.

I'm using Amazon Web services

Answer (score 2):

You need to give Access permissions to your database

Following are the links which help you to give you the Access Privlieges

[Link 1](http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-create-a-mysql-database-and-set-privileges-to-a-user)

[Link 2](http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/788/HOWTO%3a+GRANT+privileges+in+MySQL#dv)

Comment: If I want to fix this by reconnecting to the xeround database and not use localhost what should I do? Thanks for helping!

Comment: @Andy, Once the database instance becomes Active then you would be getting the confirmation mail with the IP address, you can connect to it as a regular MySQL database. Replace Localhost with the IP address, Try this